# Inject annotation in base class - Dagger still wants to add injectable constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

I'm using dagger.
Having the following classes:

```
class A {
 @Inject
 MyClass myClass;
}

class B extends A {
 myClass.do();
}
```

When trying to compile this I'm getting

> No injectable members on B . Do you want to add an injectable
>   constructor?

When moving myClass to B everything compiles. Any idea what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dagger can't know all subtypes of `A` so it doesn't know that it needs to generate adapters for classes like `B`.

Adding a no-arg constructor with `@Inject` will force the generation of code that can thus be used to perform injection on instances of `B`. You can also list `B.class` in the `injects=` list of a module to force adapter generation.